# continuos crash reports fromlibobjc.A.dylib as SIGSEGV

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, crash-reports

NON-ARC code (old project) and now am getting continuos crash reports from ***libobjc.A.dylib*** as **SIGSEGV**

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x198054000 + 113616
1   UIKit   0x18c0a8000 + 1121304
2   UIKit   0x18c0a8000 + 1121168
3   UIKit   0x18c0a8000 + 1864388
4   UIKit   0x18c0a8000 + 1862904
5   QuartzCore  0x18ba00000 + 381568
6   QuartzCore  0x18ba00000 + 381208
7   IOKit   0x188a54000 + 22736
8   CoreFoundation  0x1877e4000 + 824804
9   CoreFoundation  0x1877e4000 + 909824
10  CoreFoundation  0x1877e4000 + 909664
11  CoreFoundation  0x1877e4000 + 901344
12  CoreFoundation  0x1877e4000 + 37028
13  GraphicsServices    0x19097c000 + 46500
14  UIKit   0x18c0a8000 + 486052
15  AgendaApp   0x100030000 + 54168
16  libdyld.dylib   0x1986c8000 + 10760
```

Any clue we have here from this log. Any help is much appreciated , thanks for your time

Comment: @trojanfoe no idea at all :-| ??

Comment: Show the code around the line `AgendaApp   0x100030000 + 54168`.  Symbolication is what you'll need...

Comment: @trojanfoe AgendaApp 0x100030000 + 54168 , how can i find this line on the code?

Comment: Google "Symbolication".  As an iOS developer you need to know what that means and how to do it.  No short cuts.

Comment: Use an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html), it might help understand where the crash is coming from